# Send Email using jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, email

I am using jQuery Email template to send mail. But when I try appending image, it is unable to send the image.
Please let me know how can I embed image while sending mail using jQuery API.

Comment: https://medium.com/@mariusc23/send-an-email-using-only-javascript-b53319616782
Please refer to this url .. its almost similar

Comment: The code can can't read the image..(getting err in $ )

Comment: You are trying to use a third party library. Try `_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail` https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/send-email-in-sharepoint-2013-using-javascript/

Comment: I am using the same code your provided..still same result

Comment: is that all your error message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31300/discussion-between-debarun-sana-and-atish-dipongkor).

Comment: While I am attaching image to send using this template the image is not showing up in my mail box.. on text is coming..

Comment: It seems due to access in the Library I am unable to show them up in the mailbox..